# validate either both textbox should be filled or both should be empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've two textboxes. I need to validate whether both the textboxes are filled, only one textbox can not be filled.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="testTxtName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="testTxtGroup" runat="server" />
```

I need to do this validation on submit button click.
So the user has to fill both the textboxes or both should be left empty. Filling only one textbox is error. How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: When do you want this action to execute? On submit? This shouldn't be done *in place of* server-side validation - only for UX purposes.

Comment: I want to do this on submit button click. But can I do this using customvalidator? Please guide me I am new to javascript. Yes we can do this in server-side, but requirement is using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the server side validation handled, this is one way you could handle it on the client side.

`<form onSubmit="validateForm">`

```
function validateForm() {
    var textField1Value = document.getElementById('testTxtName').value;
    var textField2Value = document.getElementById('testTxtGroup').value;

    if ((textField1Value && !textField2Value) || (!textField1Value && textField2Value)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

a few notes on this:

- this works because in JS, an empty string is a falsey value
- returning false from a function attached to an `onSubmit` event will prevent the form submitting.
- obviously you will need to display some kind of error message, not just silently fail.

best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But please let me know , can I do the same using customvalidator? Beside the second textbox, I need to show error message, how can I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about asp :( otherwise I'd love to help. there are a million ways to show an error message, it depends what front end libraries and frameworks you have handy. Are you using a CSS framework like bootstrap? What javascript libraries are you using if any?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
        if (!txt1 && !txt2) {
            true
        }
        else if( (txt1 && !txt2)|| (!txt1 && !txt){
            alert("Please fill both textbox");
            false
        }           
        true
    }
</script>
<title></title>
```

```
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="validate();" Text="Button" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
</form>
```